# Test if a variable is a good predictor of a transition to a state

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing, vector-autoregression, hidden-markov-model

I have a dataset of the wealth of 10 different countries in the world since 1800, one data point per year.

Let's say I have noticed that when the wealth of a country goes above $1,000,000, this country goes from state A to state B (no matter what those states really mean).

What kind of statistical test can I use to try to test the hypothesis that wealth above $1,000,000 is a good predictor of the transition to state B, and in particular how do I test this hypothesis against an alternative hypothesis that it's not wealth, but population size for example that matters to make the transition?

Comment: The way you appear to be thinking about this situation isn't the right way. You have time-series data; you need to be taking the autocorrelations & cross-correlations etc into account.

Comment: @gung I don't really get why "I don't think the right way". All I do is ask a question and ask for how I can answer it. I'm not suggesting any method. If you tell me the way to answer this question is to start by calculating autocorrelations etc... then ok, do you have any links to help me go through this analysis?

Comment: My apologies, @su1, I didn't mean it personally. I was just pointing out that the answer will be more complicated & different in character than you seem to be anticipating.

Comment: @gung no problem. I don't mind if it's complicated, I just need to know where to start, so you recommend me starting with autocorrelation. No "tutorial" on the web to learn how to deal with this kind of data?